# How to migrate ExpressionFilter to log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

We are migrating from log4j 1.x to log4j 2.x and the configuration file format has changed significantly. Currently, we have these filters on one of our appenders:

```xml
<filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter">
    <param name="Expression" value="EXCEPTION ~= 'HTTP upgrade is not supported by the AJP protocol'" />
    <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="false"/>
</filter>
<filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter">
    <param name="Expression" value="CLASS ~= 'org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint'" />
    <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="false"/>
</filter>
```

These are intended to hide these two types of messages from the log; the first by the content of the reason of the exception thrown, and the second by the class of the logger. In the case of the latter, I know it seems like we could have just set a `Logger` config class for this class and turn it off, but this didn't work -- perhaps this third-party class is overriding the log configuration at runtime.

In any case, I'm trying to figure out how to migrate these to log4j2, as there no longer appears to be an `ExpressionFilter`. Your help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For filtering first type of message i.e. **filtering by content**,  you can use [RegexFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html#RegexFilter) -

```
<Filters>
    <RegexFilter regex="(?s).*?HTTP upgrade is not supported by the AJP protocol.*?" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT" />
</Filters>
```

For filtering second type i.e. **filtering by type**, you can configure `Logger` for turning off the logging of this class -

```
  <Logger name="org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint" level="OFF" additivity="false">
         <!--Write loggers here-->
   </Logger>
```

Comment: I already said that turning off the logger doesn't work for some reason, so the second one doesn't help.
The first one might work but is not as specific as the original, which was only looking at the exception, not the actual log message.

Comment: @tyrel For second point, you haven't write how you configured logger in your question. May be you haven't configured logger properly, that is why I wrote the sample. Another thing is Filtering logs using Logger is standard and well-defined way. If it is not working for you, may be logger name is different. Check logger name and set accordingly.  For first one, this is what log4j2 provides. If you find some other way, I would be happy to see and learn that.